# Order of Components in Bootstrap array matters in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Pretty new to Angular and exploring components and this may be a silly question to ask.

I was wondering whether the order of components in bootstrap array matters. Because I was curious about adding another component as a starter component apart from AppComponent. However if in index.html, I'm commenting the app-root, the second component is also not getting displayed.

Maybe it sounds confusing, appending the code as well.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, ContainerComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-container></app-container>
</body>
```

In the below picture, I'm able to see both component. However if I comment app-root, the content of app-container is not getting display.
[Reference image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qie13.png)

If I change the order of bootstrap array,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ContainerComponent, AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

then I'm able to view the content of ContainerComponent template even if AppComponent is commented.

Insights on this are very appreciated

Comment: Curiosity: why on earth you want bootstrap two components?

Comment: I'm just exploring Angular. So I was wondering what would happen if I do this?
Since there's no rule as such that you cannot add another component, I just tried this. I know its a convention that developer may often use only root component to bootstrap angular application

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to prioritize displaying the ContainerComponent first and then the AppRoot component, correct? If so, you need to make a change on the HTML side as follows

```
<body>
  <app-container></app-container>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

If you want to display only the app-container, you should update your code like this:-

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ContainerComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Additionally, add the following line at the top of your containerComponent.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-container-component', //maybe your selector name is diff verify first.
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
```

Comment: I'm not going for prioritization, I want know when commenting app-root in index.html, the content of app-container is not displaying.

Comment: Just because the selector in app.component.ts is targeting app-root, that's why it's not displaying.

Comment: FYI, you can customize your selector, as I mentioned in the code above.